# Why doesn't c++ compiler output the text on the next line while it does when putting spaces in between?

Tags: c++, whitespace

This may seem to be a duplicate question but actually its quite different because other questions don't answer my question **entirely**.My question is,why doesn't c++ compiler output the text on the next line but it does when i enter infinite spaces in between the two texts up to the next line.Like if I write like this :

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    main()
    {
      cout<<"hi
i am the king";//i have not included spaces after "hi"
}
```

It shows error : missing terminating character. Well I know that I have to include text in the quotes for the next line,but should not it be considered a white space since it is a `newline`.

While if I write the same thing including spaces like this :

```
#include<iostream>
        using namespace std;
        main()
        {
          cout<<"hi
    i am the king";//i have included spaces after "hi" up to the next line
    }
```

but it doesn't show the error,why the compiler consider spaces as white spaces here,and not the newline in the first code.I welcome the suggestions of elaborating the question if i do not make myself clear.thanks!

Comment: gcc on emacs+ windows 7

Comment: Does your 2nd line involve newline at all? Is your editors word wrap on? Possibly 2nd example is just one line?

Comment: I am curious: What is the set of rules that you use to decide whether to put a space before, after, or on both sides of a punctuation mark? It seems to be completely random.

Comment: @KarthikT no the second ain't one line i press enter after hi so it goes to next line.

Comment: FYI - The right way to do this is to end the line with a `"` and start the next line with a `"` (and put a `\n` there if you want a new line). The compiler will concatenate the two strings.

Comment: @Dukeling if you read my question carefully, i have said that i know that i need to include text between quotes but i don't know why it does concatenate spaces but not the next line, while we need not include spaces under the quotes in the next line.

Comment: Exactly how much is your definition of 'infinite'?

Comment: @Dukeling hahaha sorry,by infinite I mean spaces up to the next line.

Comment: That then points to [Karthik T's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268946/why-doesnt-c-compiler-output-the-text-on-the-next-line-while-it-does-when-put#comment25032847_17268946) - there is no new line, it just looks like there is because you have word-wrap on - no amount of spaces will insert a new-line character.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32251/discussion-between-phifounder-and-dukeling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is how C++ compiler works, according to the language specification. Space characters and newline characters are treated by the compiler differently, even though both are whitespace characters.

The behavior of the compiler is described by the language specification in the "Phases of translation" section. The compiler is required to treat each line separately. You can ask it to stitch several lines into one by using `\` at the end of the line. The compiler will not stitch lines automatically, without you explicitly asking it to do so.

It is not clear what you mean by "i have included spaces after "hi" up to the next line". If all you included are spaces, then you don't have a "next line". To start a new line you have to include a newline character.

Comment: yeah, i got that.Including spaces in between the words upto the next line doesn't make any sense because when i write them on smaller window i require few spaces but when i use larger window its in one line,so its nothing but a word wrap as stated in one of the comments,it seems to be like that but it ain't actually.

Comment: By the way I asked "why" and your answer is exactly what I asked for.thanks!!.I will go through language specification quite deeply now for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As good c++ programming habit I never increase my one line of code to more than 100 characters and it is good indentation,
So if your concern is about writing big lines of code then you should break the code into small lines by using following approach,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
      cout<<"hi                     \
      i am the king";//i have included spaces after "hi" up to the next line
}
```

Now come to your problem,

1)All c++ compiler expect ; as after end character. Your are giving new line character but not giving ; so your getting compiler error.

2)As you said that after lots of blank spaces till end character your not getting that error,

Here is one wonderful debate on stack overflow

[Do you still limit line length in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903754/do-you-still-limit-line-length-in-code)

That indicates every line has end at some point say x(This value depend on compiler what your using).
When you write code till end of the line compiler not find any new line character so for second point you will not find any error.

Comment: Ok i didn't notice the minute \ in your code,by including it we can enter text in the new line,but it concatenates the two string and make it a single line.

Comment: yes,just like putting spaces results in word wrap and hence the text goes on to the next line,i do not need to include quotes on the next line.

Comment: I'm generally against using the `\ ` at the end of a line. In the above case I'd just end the line with a `"` and start the next line with a `"`, which will cause the compiler to concatenate the strings (`"a" "b"` gets processed the same as `"ab"`). The only cases where they are required are with complex macro's, which, in my opinion, aren't used in proper C++.